# Storing JSON Object in Key Value Field

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a data structure to store some data in that accepts very specific JSON structure:

{ "NVPS": [ "NAME": "formData", "VALUE" : "myData" ] }

I'm serialising a large object that contains sub-objects into a string which I'm putting in the value field - replaces "myData" above.

```
// Serialise the form object
Map<String, String> formData = new HashMap<String, String>();
String foJson = JsonUtils.serializeJson(formObject); // returns a serialised version of formObject
formData.put("NAME", "formData");
formData.put("VALUE", foJson);

String storeJson = JsonUtils.serializeJson(formData);
storeJson = "{\"NVPS\":[" + storeJson + "]}";
```

Can anyone suggest a less ugly way I might be able to do this? I'm particularly not that happy with the last line where I create a JSON string by hand.

Here is the serializeJson() function from JsonUtils:

```
public static String serializeJson(Object dto) {
    String result = null;
    try {
        ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer();
        result = writer.writeValueAsString(dto);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String errorMsg = "Exception in serializeJson input= " + dto;
        logger.error(JSON_UTILS_DEBUG_TEXT + errorMsg);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return result;
}
```

It's using Jackson's ObjectWriter com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.

How can I clean up the first block of code?

Comment: Should `NVPS` be an array? I mean, use `[]` instead of `{}`.

Comment: No apparently not. It's a structure defined by an RFC used in a SAP system. The RFC allows for storing a JSON object, but it can't take an arbitrary JSON string - it has to be in this format:

{\"NVPS\":["NAME": "myName", "VALUE": "myValue"]}

Comment: Be aware that `{ "NVPS": [ "NAME": "formData", "VALUE" : "myData" ] }` is not a valid JSON.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure if I may have somehow messed it up in my simplification here. The final statement in the code block however does generate something that works in the storage I'm using. I think I have parsed that string before in JSONLint I'm pretty sure it passed.

Comment: `{ "NVPS": [ "NAME": "formData", "VALUE" : "myData" ] }` fails in [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll have to run what I'm actually getting through JSONLint and check. The solution you've provided looks much neater than what I've been doing. I should be able to make that in what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that `{ "NVPS": [ "NAME": "formData", "VALUE" : "myData" ] }` is not a valid JSON.

---

For valid JSON, you can try:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

ArrayNode arrayNode = mapper.createArrayNode();
arrayNode.addObject().put("NAME", "formData");
arrayNode.addObject().put("VALUE", "myData");

ObjectNode rootNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
rootNode.set("NVPS", arrayNode);

String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(rootNode);
```

It will give you:

```
{
  "NVPS" : [ {
    "NAME" : "formData"
  }, {
    "VALUE" : "myData"
  } ]
}
```

---

You also can try:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

ObjectNode objectNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
objectNode.put("NAME", "formData");
objectNode.put("VALUE", "myData");

ObjectNode rootNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
rootNode.set("NVPS", objectNode);

String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(rootNode);
```

And the result will be:

```
{
  "NVPS" : {
    "NAME" : "formData",
    "VALUE" : "myData"
  }
}
```